# How to use unity Animation Timeline

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

[image: Unity aniamtion timeline]

How to understand exact time on this timeline for example?
Its hard because I see 0.23 but its not 2300 milliseconds its 23 frames, so I need to know time in seconds.
Please help.

I tried to understand but not at all.

Comment: I know that I need to divide TimelineTime/25, but I think its dumb, isnt it?

Comment: It is not unusual that animations are based on key frame samples rather than time in seconds tbh .. the time indeed says `Seconds:Frames` so yes you would need to divide by the sample rate (that's usually why you tend to go with round numbers and not use e.g. 30 samples .. because calculations with that simply suck ^^)